# Is it possible to test multiple URLs with one test(Cypress)?

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, cypress

I'm new to Cypress test and wonder if I could test multiple URLs with one test(sample.spec.js).

Here is my sample.spec.js

```
describe("my first cypress test",()=>{
    it('navigate to eat site', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('url'))
    })
})
```

I defined env variable 'url' on cypress.json.

I was going to use this command line to test multiple URLs with one test.

```
node_modules/.bin/cypress run --spec cypress/integration/examples/sample.spec.js --env url=https://www.google.com --headed
```

Is it possible to define an url array and test all of them using Jenkins Pipeline? Plus, please let me know if there's an way to shorten the command line above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You approach is good enough by the way (in case that you will run the tests manually not via a CI tool).

To shorten the URL you can do two things:

1. Store the URL that you passed in the terminal in an environment variable in `cypress.json` file. It will be something like that:

```
{
    "env": {
        "local": "some_localhost_reference",
        "staging": "some_staging_reference",
        "production": "some_production_reference"
    }
}
```

By this you will need only to change the value in your test file to point to the environment that you want to run your tests against.

P.S. you need to move the `cy.visit()` command to a `beforeEach()` block.

2. Create a command to run cypress in your `package.json` file to be able to just type `npm run <script_name>` (`npm run cypress` in this case) in your terminal to be able to fire the cypress runner up. And it will be something like that:

```
  "scripts": {
    "cypress": "cypress open"
  }
```

If you are going to run the tests from CI, it will be dependent on the tool that you are going to use. It can do too much for you.